# How to get rid of duplicates in React when using div contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have **div contenteditable in React**

```
             <div
                className="comment-body"
                onKeyDown={addToken}
                onBlur={addComment}
                contentEditable
                data-text="Enter text here"
            >
                {renderComments()}
            </div>
```

For one method, I add a new node to the div and render a new array of text and this node, but in the div I have **duplicates**. How can this be avoided? if I use e.target.innerHTML = ' ', then how to make sure that the div is cleared first and only then the new array is rendered.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: for anyone in future, In my scenario I was maintaining the contents of 'contenteditable' div in state and when 'onfocusout' was rendering the contents inside div. This caused the contents of contentEditable div to be managed by react, so I simply had to set the contents of the 'contentEditable' by 'not using react' ie (innerHTML, etc). This solved the rendering inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ref instead of direct changes to clear the div.

```
 <div
    className="comment-body"
    ref={(ref) => { this.commentref = ref; }}
    onKeyDown={addToken}
    onBlur={addComment}
    contentEditable
    data-text="Enter text here"
>
    {renderComments()}
</div>
```

Then you should clear the div after adding the new one.

Comment: Can you provide more details please?